# What are the reasons to not use unicode values instead of HTML values?

Tags: java, html, unicode, encoding, wicket

This is kind of a "best practices" question, but also asking from a functional standpoint. Why would you want to use an HTML value such as ® instead of /u00AE?

With an application that does a lot of internationalization the data is in .properties files and then loaded into the HTML using the Wicket framework.

**Example A:**
Properties File

```
companyName=My Company\u00AE
```

HTML File

```
<wicket:message key="companyName"/>
```

**Example B:**
Properties File

```
companyName=My Company
```

HTML File

```
<wicket:message key="companyName"/>&reg;
```

Does one example limit usage or functionality? Is it just a style choice?

Comment: The first paragraph of your post appears to ask a totally different question than the rest of the post. If you have both questions, please open two topics.

Comment: @TAM I don't think so. I'm providing a clear example of when I would use both and asking if there is a reason one would be better, whether that would be from a "best practices" standpoint or a functional standpoint.

Answer (score 1):

if ® will be used whatever the locale, I could see why it would be useless to have it in the property file.

Now, if this thing might be different from one locale to the other, then putting it in the property file makes sense.

Another reason to put that kind of characters are that unicode is not clear what is the character behind \u00AE. "®" gives you a hint about what it is.

Another way is to a have another property registeredTrademark = \u00AE

and then in the html:

```
<wicket:message key="companyName"/> <wicket:message key="registeredTrademark"/>
```

But that would be overkill unless this registeredTrademark is used in log of places.